# How do I quote a paragraph that already has a footnote?

Tags: quotes, footnotes

Suppose I have the following paragraph that already has a footnote in it:

> This was a misunderstanding from some imprecise writing (and was related to #14 above). The argument is with respect to the size of shoots not needles. \footnote{This has been clarified in the discussion at great length.}

How do I quote the above paragraph with quotation marks? What do I do with the footnote in the paragraph?

Comment: Footnotes aren't usually printed as "\footnote..." within the text itself. Are you talking about something printed as you have quoted, or something that has a (proper) footnote?

Comment: @Lawrence I wanted to include the Latex code to produce the footnote. Yes, something that has a proper footnote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen three approaches that I can think of:

1. If the footnote is not relevant to you — if your only reason for including it is that the source had it — then don't worry, you can simply omit it. Just as you can quote a paragraph without including the paragraphs before and after it, you can quote a paragraph without including any footnotes to it.
2. If the footnote is relevant to you, but only secondarily, you can follow the quotation with a comment along the lines of "A footnote adds that '...'." (This comment can be in the main text, or in parentheses, or a footnote, as you prefer.)
3. If the footnote is highly relevant to you, you can "promote" it into the quotation by using a format like "[footnote: ...]". But this is disruptive, and gives the footnote greater prominence than the author gave it, so should be used with caution.

In my experience, #1 is more common than #2, and #2 is more common than #3.